# Referring to file images on directory of installation python

Tags: python, image, installation

I'm developing an application that use some images on html code to show on jupyter cell like the following:

```
display(HTML('''<center><img src ="image/image1.png" style="height:150px;width:340px" /></center>'''))
```

And when we use this code this work well. But when we make the installation of the package the code can't find the images from installation directory, I checked the directory and all images are in the same place with the same structure. How can I make a correct reference to images on instalation directory?

Comment: you could try import os
os.chdir('/path/to/images')

Comment: What are the permissions on the `image` subfolder and the files in it?

Comment: @Chris but is possible to make this in a dynamic way?

Comment: @JohnGordon At first I do not set any permissions on the files. Theoretically they are accessible. Is it possible to set the access level in the setup.py file?

Comment: _Theoretically they are accessible_ Theory is great, but you should actually check.  Does the web server run as a specific user id, and are the files accessible by that user?  Can you log in to the host as the web user and cd to the `image` directory?

Comment: Look at the webserver access log to see the image URLs that are failing.  Are those the correct URLs?